# Extract Segments from String using Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to extract text from one of my HTML pages using a regular expression but am slightly stuck as to how I can differentiate between the different sections of the content...

Consider this HTML (the new lines are not actually present in the code):

```
Name: SOMETHING_HERE<br>
Gender: SOMETHING_HERE<br>
Age: SOMETHING_HERE<br>
etc...
```

Using `preg_match()`, I would like to get the values of SOMETHING_HERE. So, anything that comes after the ':' and before the '`<br>`' I would like to catch and add to the matches array.

This is my somewhat pathetic attempt so far:

```
$regex = '/[^:]+:\s*(.+)\s*\<br\>/i';
```

The above seems to match the whole string instead of each part, can anyone advise what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go with this `/:(.*?)<br>/`

```
<?php

$str='Name: SOMETHING_HERE<br>
Gender: SOMETHING_HERE<br>
Age: SOMETHING_HERE<br>';
preg_match_all('/:(.*?)<br>/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  SOMETHING_HERE
    [1] =>  SOMETHING_HERE
    [2] =>  SOMETHING_HERE
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
(?<=\:\s).*?(?=\<)
```

regex demo here : http://regex101.com/r/sT8xC0